Can I use custom monads with effect-ts?
I often use monads in TypeScript and define them from scratch, and have always missed HKTs so I can define generic functions that apply to all monads such as a generic map or some sort of Haskell-like do notation.
I was about to start digging into fp-ts but I just found out it's being merged with effect-ts, which looks like a pretty neat package and as far as I understand, it uses a better way to encode HKTs.
It looks to me like Effect is a combination of several monads into one, and I wonder if there's a way to plug my own monads there. For instance, I want to be able to use the array monad such that I can construct an Effect<number, ...> from an array of numbers that get flattened out when I call Effect.flatMap. If I'm not mistaken, as long as there's a way to use Effect as a continuation monad, I should be able to emulate every other monad, but it doesn't look like Effect includes a continuation monad. I don't have much information about the Effect.runCallback but it seems to me like the callback is called only once when the evaluation completes, while a real continuation would require a way to receive a callback multiple times.
So I wonder if I'm missing something or perhaps I should be using fp-ts instead since I'm interested mostly in using my own monads, and not so much about the myriad of utility functions provided by Effect.

...I love writing code that's generic over a shared abstraction as much as the next functional programmer, but I recommend against this in the strongest possible terms. If we're talking about production code it's almost always better to use a common abstraction that maybe isn't exactly what you want over a custom one that does exactly what you want but only you can understand without extensive perusal of the source. Unless this is for educational purposes, just use Effect.

Yes you can use effect-ts to define custom monads.  I have recently moved from fp-ts to effect-ts because of the merger of the projects.  Things are done a little differently in effect-ts and you need to install @effect/typeclass on top of the standard effect package.  There isn't currently much documentation on how to use these classes vs fp-ts, but there are enough similarities to make knowing how fp-ts work is good background reading.
The HKT type in effect-ts is neccessarily more complex the key difference is that fp-ts uses a central registry (URItoKind) as a map for HKTs, whereas effect-ts uses a more decentralized approach where each TypeLambda carries its own implementation of how it should be interpreted by Kind - see article below which is very helpful in explaining.
Anyway the code below creates a trivial new HKT X which simply contains a value keyed on x of type A.  We then write a functor and monad for X, and then show chaining the monad and a handful of other monad utilities like flatten you get for free with effect.
I've also included a ref below to a repo I'm writing which shows many of the classic LYAH problems in effect-ts - it's messy and I often veer off course, because I find something interesting to persue in effect-ts - but here there are many examples of using HKTs and various fp constructs in effect - functors, monoids, applicative, monads, etc.  You can find an example of "Pierre's" monad example from LYAH, or at least something like it there!
// -*- compile-command: "npx ts-node basic-custom-monad.ts" -*-

import { pipe, dual } from "effect/Function";
import type { Covariant as CovariantType } from "@effect/typeclass/Covariant";
import { Monad as MonadType } from "@effect/typeclass/Monad";
import { flatten, zipRight, composeK } from "@effect/typeclass/FlatMap";
import type { Kind, TypeLambda } from "effect/HKT";

// Define the custom and trivial HKT X
type X<A> = {
  x: A;
};

// Define TypeLambda for X
interface XTypeLambda extends TypeLambda {
  readonly type: X<this["Target"]>;
}

// Covariant (Functor) instance for XTypeLambda
const CovariantX: CovariantType<XTypeLambda> = {
  map: dual(
    2,
    <R, O, E, A, B>(
      fa: Kind<XTypeLambda, R, O, E, A>,
      f: (a: A) => B
    ): Kind<XTypeLambda, R, O, E, B> => {
      return { x: f(fa.x) };
    }
  ),

  // Implementing 'imap' for bidirectional mapping (A -> B and B -> A)
  imap: dual(
    3,
    <R, O, E, A, B>(
      fa: Kind<XTypeLambda, R, O, E, A>,
      to: (a: A) => B,
      from: (b: B) => A
    ): Kind<XTypeLambda, R, O, E, B> => {
      return { x: to(fa.x) };
    }
  )
};

// Monad instance for XTypeLambda
const MonadX: MonadType<XTypeLambda> = {
  // 'of' creates an X container around a value
  of: <A>(value: A): Kind<XTypeLambda, unknown, never, never, A> => ({ x: value }),

  // 'flatMap' applies a function f to the value inside X and returns a new X
  flatMap: dual(
    2,
    <R1, O1, E1, A, R2, O2, E2, B>(
      fa: Kind<XTypeLambda, R1, O1, E1, A>,
      f: (a: A) => Kind<XTypeLambda, R2, O2, E2, B>
    ): Kind<XTypeLambda, R1 & R2, O1 | O2, E1 | E2, B> => {
      return f(fa.x);
    }
  ),

  // 'map' reuses the implementation from Covariant
  map: CovariantX.map,
  imap: CovariantX.imap
};

// Example of chaining results
const result = pipe(
  MonadX.of(2),
  MonadX.flatMap((n: number) => MonadX.of(n * 2)),
  MonadX.flatMap((n: number) => MonadX.of(`${n}!`))
);

console.log(result); // Output: { x: "4!" }


// Additional examples using functions from FlatMap

// Example 1: Using `flatten`
const nested = MonadX.of(MonadX.of(42)); // { x: { x: 42 } }
const flattened = flatten(MonadX)(nested);
console.log(flattened); // Output: { x: 42 }

// Example 2: Using `zipRight`, discarding the first result of 2
const resultZipRight = zipRight(MonadX)(MonadX.of(2), MonadX.of("Second!"));
console.log(resultZipRight); // Output: { x: "Second!" }

// Example 3: Using `composeK`
const composed = composeK(MonadX)(
  (n: number) => MonadX.of(n + 1),
  (n: number) => MonadX.of(n * 2)
);

const resultComposed = composed(3); // First add 1 -> 4, then multiply by 2 -> 8
console.log(resultComposed); // Output: { x: 8 }

Ref:

https://effect.website/docs/other/behaviour/hkt
https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/issues/1941#issuecomment-2329577058
https://github.com/falloutphil/lya-effect-ts

